# Displaying external web pages that do not allow iframe embedding in WinJS

Tags: winjs

My current understanding is that the only way to display external web pages in the WinJS app is to use iframes. This seems to be a limitation, since I am not able to embed youtube links or twitter search links.

eg. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diP-o_JxysA

How do I go about displaying these webpages? Are there any workarounds for this limitation other than the run your own proxy solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot without running your own proxy and modifying the headers, or modifying the headers directly on the host server.

Note that for other types of resources, like login pages that don't like to be iframed (e.g. Salesforce.com), you can use the [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750287.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately this seems to be a limitation for winjs apps. Thanks.